# Openshift 3 WAR

Tags: maven, tomcat, openshift, pom.xml, openshift-3

In the Openshift 2 I had such a profile in a `pom.xml` file:

```
    <profile>
        <!-- openshift red hat cloud build profile -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

and this was responsible for putting a WAR file to directory from where it was automatically deployed to Tomcat-like-jboss.

Now - in Openshift 3 - by using browser-embeded `ssh` console I checked that WAR files were build and put into `/tmp/src/webapps` directory. Where should I move it (how should I modify the Maven profile) to make new Openshift 3 Tomcat-like-jboss deploy it and host it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answear - the correct `outputDirectory` is `target`, so the WAR plugin looks now:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                  <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

I've found it there: https://github.com/gshipley/book-helloworld/blob/master/pom.xml - in a sample OpenShift app. Now my WAR are being deployed to the WildFly!

Moreover - this free e-book is really heplful: https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html.